# How do I obtain the height and width of a given YUV video clip under Matlab? Is there any reader() function or get() function? Anything else?

Tags: matlab, yuv

How to get the width and height of a given yuv file? The dimensions are needed for subsequent movie/matrix processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the help of [VIDEOREADER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/videoreaderclass.html)

```
%# create reader object (does not load file yet)
xyloObj = VideoReader('xylophone.mpg');

%# query dimensions
nFrames = xyloObj.NumberOfFrames;
vidHeight = xyloObj.Height;
vidWidth = xyloObj.Width;
```

**EDIT**

For older versions of Matlab, you can use [AVIINFO](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/aviinfo.html) to query the properties of a movie.

Comment: But it seems that VideoReader is not a build-in function in Matlab, is it?

Comment: @yoursclark: The link I provide in my answer does point to the official Matlab documentation, so yes, it is a built-in function in more recent versions of Matlab. However, the function has not been around forever. Which version are you working with?

Comment: Oh I see. I'm currently using Matlab R2008a. So I guess the function is not accessible under my version?

Comment: @yoursclark: Looks like it. In your version, `aviinfo` should do the job, though. Check the link in my edit.